# Equivalent of console.log in C#

Tags: c#

I am running an MVC Web application built by using Visual Studio 2017. I want to test some parts of C# code `without using debugger breakpoints`. Is there any way to know a certain part of code has run by adding some code at that point? Something like  `console.log` in Javascript? As to make things more specific I'd like to add this "watcher code" inside the following method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}
```

Is the above doable and how?

Comment: How about [System.Diagnostics.Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine`

Comment: You can use [`Console` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[`Trace.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) will do (and probably more methods from the [`Trace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) class).

You can use a program called [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to real-time monitor the trace generated, or [write to a log file using you `web.config` file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0ectfxd.aspx).

Comment: If writing Trace.WriteLine("Hello")  where will I get "Hello"?

Comment: Depends where you store it. Did you read the documentation I referenced?

Comment: TraceSource class can also be used for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have enabled the Debugger. I have added  `Trace.WriteLine("Hello");` inside Main method but I cannot see "Hello" in the output window of VS

Comment: It should be visible there. Try to use a new console application and see if it works. Then you can diagnose where it goes wrong.

Comment: With the console application it works. The problem is my application is a web one

Comment: Then probably MVC does something to the trace. Not sure. Does using DebugView work?

Comment: I can see it now. Thank you

Answer (score 19):

[`System.Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-7.0) will do it provided that you have a console to view it in (for a forms application this works when debugging in something like visual studio, but the end user will never see the output).

Comment: Ofc this is required
`using System;`

Comment: Thanks @AffesSalem, I've added the namespace to the answer for clarity.

Answer (score 18):

Try using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is a log");` and in Visual Studio open `View` and then in `Output` you will see the log when running your application.